# Need to assign a region code to a Dataframe field based on the State abbreviation or full state name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes one with the region code, state abbreviation and state name.  The target dataframe has a state field that either has the two character state abbreviation or the full state name.  I am currently iterating through the target dataframe and doing an if statement to match the abbreviation or full name and if there is a match I update the region code.  Currently the code take a couple of hours to run through the 460k records in the target dataframe.  Is there a more efficient way to code this task?
My code looks like the following:

```
reg_list = pd.read_csv('Regions.csv', sep = ';')
reg_list['st_upper'] = reg_list.State.str.upper()
cons_pcp_with_address['reg_cd'] = 99
for x, regx in reg_list.iterrows():
    for y, row in cons_pcp_with_address.iterrows():
        if cons_pcp_with_address.loc[y,'Provider Business Practice Location Address State Name'] == 
            reg_list.loc[x,'Abbr'] or 
            cons_pcp_with_address.loc[y,'Provider Business Practice Location 
            Address State Name'] == 
            reg_list.loc[x,'st_upper']:cons_pcp_with_address.loc[y,'reg_cd'] = 
            reg_list.loc[x,'Region']            
    y = 0
```

Comment: multiprocessing will help.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it.